# WYSIWYG Help Documentation Generators

Tags: wysiwyg, help-files

**I am looking for applications/3rd party libraries that can create online(.html) and offline(.hlp) help documentation for our application.**

Does anyone know of good help documentation generaters that have either a WYSIWYG interface or are a API(involving HTML, CSS, .NET C# but not PHP).

I know of Dr Explain – http://www.drexplain.com/ – which is good but expensive. Does anyone know of any other applications that perform the same things but is cheaper or even free?

Answer (score 1):

Try http://chmprocessor.sourceforge.net/ - it creates help files in a variety of common formats.